# How can I prove an airline ticket is fake?

Tags: tickets, airlines, scams

My friend was sent a picture of an airline ticket that a guy on Facebook has bought for her.

How can I prove this is a fake and that she is being scammed? Her flight is Thai Air flight BF120 from SEA to PAH (Barkley Regional) xtkt 0372314080023.

I thought tickets were supposed to be 14 digits long. How can I look this up to prove to her it’s fake and save her from going to the airport and being devastated because it’s fake and to stop her from sending him any more money?

---

This is my first time on here but I’m sure you all hear this all the time. My friend had a tragic year loosing her husband to Covid and 6 months later loosing her daughter in a horrific car accident. She is lonely and vulnerable and I am just trying to protect her. Thank you for all the advice. I told her today of my worries and showed her all your comments.

Comment: Well, there's no way Thai Air is flying to Barkely Regional in Kentucky. It could be a code share but BF is the French Bee low-cost airline, which I'm sure also doesn't fly to Barkley Regional.

Comment: I have a strange feeling of déjà vu. Maybe someone asked a similar question in the past, although it wasn't the same picture.

Comment: As well as the answers to your question, have your friend read [Romance scammers’ favorite lies exposed](https://www.ftc.gov/news-events/data-visualizations/data-spotlight/2023/02/romance-scammers-favorite-lies-exposed) and [Online Imposters Break Hearts and Bank Accounts](https://www.fbi.gov/news/stories/romance-scams), there are many many other warnings out there

Comment: ΅how can I prove this ticket is fake": very easily. take literally any fact on this picture, and try to prove it is true.

Comment: Wow, that's a bad fake. Flight number is wrong , Airline code is wrong, route doesn't exist, it's a boarding pass from the future (time travel is always fun), eticket number is wrong in length and prefix, etc. Please help your friend!

Comment: These romance scams are the most offensive to me. Sorry.

Comment: @Hilmar ticket from the future is intentional, as the friend is supposed to use it in the future.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Yes, a ticket from the future would be fine, but this is a boarding pass - as  Hilmar implies, these are issued only on the day of travel.

Comment: Perhaps you could google "how to educate someone about romance scams" to find other points that will persuade your friend that something is badly wrong with this.

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill It looks like someone altered the question history so that not even the first revision contains the pictures anymore.

Comment: Review the questions at https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sugar-daddy . All of them should sound familiar, your friend is being scammed.

Comment: @Clockwork Yes, I think it came to the attention of the mods. A sanitised version is in one of the answers below, as is the original that the scammer doctored.

Comment: This is my first time on here but I’m sure you all hear this all the time. My friend had a tragic year loosing her husband to Covid and on this later loosing her daughter in a horrific car accident. She is lonely and vulnerable and I am just trying to protect her. Thank you for all the advice. I told her today of my worries and showed her all your comments. Thank you all

Comment: @DianaThompson, if you feel one of the answers is the most helpful, please accept it by clicking on the tick next to it.

Comment: Please do all you can to help her, those repugnant bastards don’t care who they hurt. I have a dear friend who was taken for a large amount (enough to affect her life, let alone the psychological damage). I won’t say what should be done to them but it would be permanent and painful.

Comment: @Clockwork yes - the site mods have a rarely-used function called "redact" which removes things from the edit history.  It requires a second moderator to approve any change, and is mostly used to hide PII / PPI like names and ID numbers that shouldn't be in the question or the edit history.  There's nothing malicious in the redaction, the poor target of this scam has suffered enough already.

Comment: For what it's worth, I haven't seen a paper airline ticket in probably more than a decade (maybe two decades).  They are pretty rare now (if they exist at all).

Comment: Flight [BF-120](https://www.flightaware.com/live/flight/BF120) does not exist.

Comment: Why not take the ticket to the airline?

Answer (score 55):

For starters, *that's not a picture of an airline ticket!*  It's a boarding pass of the sort that is printed and given to the passenger no more than a few hours before the flight. That document, if it really was issued for a flight on October 10th, would have to have been issued on October 10th 2022 or in some earlier year.

The first three digits of an ETKT number identify the airline.  The code [037 is for USAir](http://www.kovrik.com/sib/travel/airline-codes.txt), not Thai (which is 217).

Answer (score 45):

Several indicators show this "boarding pass" to be bogus.

a) The "boarding pass" displays the Thai Airways logo, but Thai Airways doesn't provide service to Seattle (it used to do so, but doesn't now), and certainly not to Barkley Regional Airport in Kentucky. No other connecting flights are shown, only a non-existent flight "120."

b) [Flightaware.com](https://www.flightaware.com/live/flight/THA120) shows Thai Flight 120 is a domestic flight within Thailand, going from Bangkok to Chiang Mai.

c) The "boarding pass" doesn't show a six-digit Passenger Name Record.

I'm sure there's more. The real problem here, however, is how to communicate with your friend, and persuade them of the falsity of the document. That's way beyond the scope of this SE site. I think this underlying question should be asked on [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thai's flights are coded TG, not BF 

Comment: BF120 does not exist

Comment: PNR are not six-digits, they're six alpha-numeric characters: digits and uppercase, with confusing uppercase characters removed.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I agree. I used the word "digits" in its colloquial sense as "either a letter or a single-place number."

Comment: Worth mentioning that *no* foreign airlines provide domestic flights in the US (it's illegal). Not just Thai.

Answer (score 41):

Besides all the flaws already mentioned (it's a boarding pass and not a ticket, boarding passes are not issued days in advance, airline is wrong, flight is non-existent, etc.) a quick easy search ("Search image with Google Lens) gives us the original boarding pass from 10+ years ago:

[image]

(found on [this website](https://grownuptravelguide.com/long-haul-flights-first-business-class-less-economy-fare-part-1/9)).

---

The fake boarding pass:

[image]

---

**Edit: some of the obvious mistakes in the fake boarding pass.**

- There is no **gate A03** at SEA. It would have been gate A3.
- They kept the MXP1CKB506 and MPXII at the bottom, both indicating that the boarding pass is for MPX (Milan-Malpensa)
- The B's in BF and in 2B look weird (compare with the B06 in the good boarding pass).
- The flight number doesn't exist, and the airline code is for an airline that does not fly in the US.
- There are no direct flights SEA-PAH.

Interestingly, they took the time to change the sequence number, which is internal information for the airline (it usually means the order in which the person checked-in, i.e. SEQ8 means that the passenger is the 8th person to check-in for the flight).

Comment: It's weird that that they edited the seat number and sequence number, seems a lot of effort for things that are not really consequential

Comment: Indeed. Or using a Thai boarding pass to try to pass as a domestic US flight. They tried to put some unneeded subtlety into a very crude attempt.

Comment: Now I want to see the the boarding pass that the OP originally posted (and was removed because of the PII)

Comment: I have included a sanitized version of the fake picture. It is still viewable through the edit history.

Comment: Thanks for posting the sanitized version. Your mods are working on removing it from the edit history.

Comment: I stupidly was looking for an actual image in the edit history.  But some of those changes are weird.  If you wanted to have fun you could put a red box around all the differences, and list them in you answer.

Comment: @PeterM, moderators can, working with more than one of them, remove information out of the history of the question. We only do it if the information can damage a person. It does leave a strange history.

Comment: A few other things I noticed.  The boarding time was changed from "1325" (without a colon) to "10:00" (with a colon).  The date was changed from "08JUN" (no space) to "10 OCT" (with a space).  The detachable part now includes the airport code.  And the width of the "FROM" field used to print "SEATAC / SEA" is different from "MILAN  / MXP" (and  the same for the "TO" field)

Comment: @mousetail: The best I can think of is that if they change everything, then it all looks consistent; as opposed to changing only a few things and those bad edits sticking out like a sore thumb.

Answer (score 26):

A short list of incongruities:

- Thai doesn't do US domestic flights. Especially not to Podunk, OH. Even in Thailand it doesn't do smaller airports. Its low-cost subsidiary does.
- Thai's airline code is TG not BF.
- BF120 as a flight doesn't seem to exist.
- This is not a ticket, but a boarding pass, for October 10. Even an electronic boarding pass wouldn't be given so early in advance, let alone a printed boarding pass...
- Only Contour Airlines flies to Barkley, from Charlotte.

There's probably more...

Comment: "Especially not to Podunk, OH" per the question... its Bumblescutt, Kentucky not Podunk, Ohio.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Podunk

Answer (score 18):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barkley_Regional_Airport

> It is used for general aviation and sees one airline, subsidized by the Essential Air Service program. The only airline is Contour Airlines, with Embraer 145 flights to Charlotte Douglas International Airport in Charlotte, North Carolina.

Answer (score 13):

A generally consolidated list of issues with this:

- This is a boarding pass, not a ticket. Some people conflate the two, but they are *very* different things.
- Boarding passes are only issued within 48 hours before the flight they are for, and are only usable for that specific instance of that specific flight. This one has a date of October 10, which, given the current date of 2023-10-07, means it cannot be valid for any future flight.
- Thai Airways International uses IATA airline code TG for their flights, not BF, so the flight code is not a Thai Airways International flight (despite the boarding pass having the correct livery for Thai Airways International).
- The IATA code BF is assigned to French Bee SAS, a low-cost regional airline that only operates out of Paris Orly Airport (ORY). SEA is not on their destination list, and PAH definitely isn’t (none of their fleet could take off there, the whole fleet are A350's and the runways are below the 2km MTRL for that aircraft).
- BF 120 does not seem to be a registered flight code for French Bee (which makes sense, they only serve eight destinations).
- Boarding passes are (almost) always printed with the underlying flight code, not any codeshare code, so it’s unlikely that BF 120 designates a codeshare.
- If we assume a misprint of some sort and look up flight TG 120, we see that it’s a domestic flight within Thailand (Bangkok to Chiang Mai).
- Thai Airways International does not currently have SEA as a destination, and they definitely don’t have PAH. They do have a lot of codeshare agreements (they’re one of the Star Alliance carriers), so in theory a flight too or from SEA *could* be booked through them, but as mentioned above, the underlying flight code would be printed on the pass, not the codeshare code. None of their codeshare partners serve PAH either though
- PAH is only served by one commercial airline, Contour Airlines (IATA code LF), and they are definitely not in any codeshare or interline agreements with French Bee or Thai Airways International.
- The e-ticket number is the wrong length, but only because of the airlines involved. A 13-digit code is technically valid because the check digit is not always mandatory, but both Thai Airways International and French Bee use 14-digit e-ticket numbers.
- The e-ticket number has the wrong prefix. Thai Airways International has the prefix 217. 037 was historically US Airways, which merged into American Airlines in 2015. As far as I know, it was never reassigned, so it’s not even a valid prefix anymore.
- While the boarding pass does not have a PNR number, this is normal for a Thai Airways International boarding pass, so it’s not actually an issue.

Comment: It turns out that the e-ticket number is real, just from many years ago (see picture in [my answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/183983/10087)).